# Why is there greyed, unclickable usernames?

Tags: support

I have just seen an answer and three comments with their usernames all acting weird:

> [image: (FAINTED)]

What's going on here?  It's definitely not migration, and the "deleted-users-username-change-to-user-id" thing had already occurred on 2012 which is 6 years earlier than the year the four posts were uploaded.  Is this a bug?  Or by design?

Link to posts: https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/a/6478/7708

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the question was migrated from [Music Practice and Theory](https://music.stackexchange.com/). These accounts still exist but that users are not member of Music Fans.